# Partition in Equivalence sets

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a simple, non-dirictional tree `T`. I should find a path named `A` and another named `B` that `A` and `B` have no common vertex. The perpuse is to maxmize the `Len(A)*Len(B)`.

I figured this problem is similer to Partition Problem, except in Partition Problem you have a set but here you have a Equivalence set. The solution is to find two uncrossed path that `Len(A) ~ Len(B) ~ [n-1/2]`. Is this correnct? how should I impliment such algorithm?

Comment: Your question is confusing. How do you define len(A) if it is non-directional ? Also correct the spelling mistakes in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. I Think you are looking at this problem the wrong way. As I understand it you have a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) related problem. What you do is

> 1. Build a maximum spanning tree and find the length L.
> 2. Now, you say that the two paths can't have any vertex in common, so we have to remove an edge to archieve this. I assume that every edge wheight in your graph is 1. So sum of the two paths A and B are L-1 after you removed an edge. The problem is now that you have to remove an edge such that the product of len(a) and len(b) is maximized. You do that by removeing the edge in et most 'middel' of L. Why, the problem is of the same  as optimizing the area of a rectangle with a fixed perimeter. A short youtube video on the subject can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hqi7gls2pI).

Note if your edge wheights are not equal to 1, then you have a harder problem, because there may exist more than one maximum spanning tree. But you may be able to split them in different ways, if this is the case, write me back, then I will think about a solution, but i do not have one at hand.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a dynamic programming solution that is just about tractable if path length is just the number of links in the paths (so links don't have weights).

Work from the leaves up. At each node you need to keep track of the best pair of solutions confined to the subtree with root at that node, and, for each k, the best solution with a path of length k terminating in that node and a second path of maximum length somewhere below that node and not touching the path.

Given this info for all descendants of a node, you can produce similar info for that node, and so work your way up to the route.

You can see that this amount of information is required if you consider a tree that is in fact just a line of nodes. The best solution for a line of nodes is to split it in two, so if you have only worked out the best solution when the line is of length 2n + 1 you won't have the building blocks you need for a line of length 2n + 3.